# Extracting and replacing value in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to replaces the values from dictionary type to numeric value as the example below. How could I extract them and change the values in the DataFrame?

eg.)

```
{'kWh': '-107.368'} -> -107.368
{'kWh': '-143.982'} -> -143.982
```

[image: DataFrame screenshot]

Comment: It is always advised not to post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, Use [`Series.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.transform.html) to transform the dictionaries to corresponding numeric value with key `kWh` inside dictionary:

```
df['544299'] = df['544299'].transform(lambda d: float(d.get('kWh', np.nan)))
```

---

You can also use [`Series.str.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html):

```
df['544299'] = df['544299'].str.get('kWh').astype(float).abs()
```

Comment: It totally worked! Thank you! Could I change the output values to positive?

Comment: @yeonhodev Yes you can simply use `abs(float(d.get('kWh', np.nan)))`

Comment: @yeonhodev You should use `d.get('kWh', np.nan)` in case your dictionary does not contains the key `kWh`, `x['kWh']` will throw an error.

Comment: Can't think of why it fires the error...

solar_data['544299'] = solar_data['544299'].transform(lambda d: abs(float(d.get('kWh', np.nan)))
solar_data

  File "<ipython-input-88-9a9060d63b86>", line 2
    solar_data
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @yeonhodev You have a missing brace. add extra ending brace. Use `solar_data['544299'] = solar_data['544299'].transform(lambda d: abs(float(d.get('kWh', np.nan))))`

Comment: @anky Good to know, but `df['544299'].get('kWh')` returning `None`? What's the problem here?

Comment: Sorry to ask more question here, but how could I change the index from datetime to date only? I would like to get rid of the useless time value from index.

Comment: @anky Amazing that's better, didn't knew about that thanks for letting me know. Should i update the answer with this solution?

Comment: @yeonhodev Just use `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` if you want index as `datetime` or use  `df.index = df.index.str.split().str[0]` if you want index as string.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Amazing!! That's exactly what I wanted! Thank you for your guidance!

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I was using your second solution with Series.str.get. I found out that it works fine on Jupyter both on Windows and Mac, but not on Ubuntu environment when I tried to run it as .py file. The values were replaced as NaN somehow only on Ubuntu. I ended up using your first solution which works everywhere. Do you have any idea why it doesn't work on Ubuntu by any chance?

Comment: @yeonhodev well that seems strange behaviour,  I guess it should work on all the platforms equally. Could you be able to send me your code(.py file) so that i can reproduce the problem here on my ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 2):

The `.apply()` method works:

```
df[column] = df[column].apply(
   lambda x: float(x['kWh'])
)
```

Comment: It totally worked! Thank you! Could I change the output values to positive?

Comment: It resolved as below. Thank you very much!!!

solar_data['544299'] = solar_data['544299'].apply(
   lambda x: abs(float(x['kWh']))
)